# what is the relation between of minimal polynomials of elements of two isomorphic fields?

Tags: field-theory

Assume that $F$ be a field and $f(x)$ be an irreducible polynomial in $F[x]$. Suppose that $\alpha, \beta$ be two distinct root of $f(x)$. So, there exists an isomorphism $\sigma$ from  $F(\alpha)$ to $F(\beta)$. Consider that $h(x)$ be an irreducible polynomial in $F(\alpha)[x]$. So, $\sigma(h(x))$ is  an irreducible polynomial in $F(\beta)[x]$. Assume that $a$ be a root of $h(x)$ and $g(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $F$. Is it true that the minimal polynomial of any root of  $\sigma(h(x))$ over $F$ is  $g(x)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Consider the following steps.

1. $h(x)$ is a factor of $g(x)$ in the ring $F(\alpha)[x]$.
2. Therefore $\sigma(h(x))$ is a factor of $\sigma(g(x))$ in the ring $F(\beta)[x]$.
3. But $\sigma(g(x))=g(x)$ because $g(x)\in F[x]$.
4. Therefore any zero of $\sigma(h(x))$ is also a zero of $g(x)$.
5. But as the minimal polynomial of some element $g(x)$ is irreducible in $F[x]$. Therefore it is automatically the minimal polynomial (over $F$) of any of its zeros in whichever extension field of $F$ that zero happens to lie.